# R data frame: select rows that meet logical conditions over multiple columns (variables) indexed by name

Tags: r

Ok this example should clarify what I am looking for

```
set.seed(123456789)

df <- data.frame(
  x1 = sample(c(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  x2 = sample(c(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  z1 = sample(c(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE)
  )
```

I want to select all rows that have x1 and x2 =1. That is,

```
df[df$x1==1 & df$x2==1,]
```

which returns

```
   x1 x2 z1
1   1  1  1
4   1  1  1
6   1  1  1
10  1  1  0
```

but I want to do it in a way that scales to many x variables (e.g. x1,x2,...x40), so I would like to index the columns by "x" rather than having to write df$x1==1 & df$x2==1 &... & df$x40==1. Note that I care about having the z1 variable in the resulting data set (i.e. while the rows are selected based on the x variables, I am not looking to select the x columns only). Is it possible?

Comment: Are the `x` columns defined by a regex or other known criteria?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Not 100% sure I know what that means (sorry) but in my actual data frame I would generate the x columns based on a number of countries in the data. So say there are 3 countries named A, B, C then it would be x.A x.B x.C. generated using a loop over the country names. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: If you know the columns names, you can put those names in a vector `cols` and my answer would work.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Hi mate, yes your solution works well. I have not marked it as my preferred answer because it's a bit longer and less readable for me. But would solve my problem just fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution, based on `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123456789)

df <- data.frame(
  x1 = sample(c(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  x2 = sample(c(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  z1 = sample(c(0,1), size = 10, replace = TRUE)
)

df %>% 
  filter(across(starts_with("x"), ~ .x == 1))

#>   x1 x2 z1
#> 1  1  1  1
#> 2  1  1  1
#> 3  1  1  1
#> 4  1  1  0
```

Comment: Thanks ! it works great. Can you explain what `~ .x` means?

Comment: You are welcome, @mariodrumblue! `~ .x ==1` is equivalent to `f(x) x == 1`, where `x` means the column of the dataframe that `across` is giving successively. Is now clear to you?

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Yet it's clearer now. I have picked up R recently and still getting around certain syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R way with `Reduce` applied to the data.frame's rows.

```
cols <- grep("^x", names(df))

i <- apply(df[cols], 1, \(x) Reduce(`&`, x == 1L))
df[i,]
#   x1 x2 z1
#1   1  1  1
#4   1  1  1
#6   1  1  1
#10  1  1  0
```